# GA4 event firing twice on Vue async method

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, vuejs3, gtag.js

I've been trying to track a product selection on my website using vue-gtag. The event is sent using an abstraction I created called 'notification'. I've been capturing all events successfully except this one which is being fire twice for some reason.

Here's the piece of code:

```
    methods: {
        ...mapActions('menu', {
            updateCurrentProduct: 'updateCurrentProduct',
            getOriginators: 'getOriginators',
        }),

        async selectProduct(product, parent) {
            await this.$dialog.confirm({
                text: 'Deseja realmente alterar? Você será reiniciado para a tela inicial.',
                title: 'Alterar produto',
                actions: {
                    false: {
                        text: 'Cancelar',
                        color: 'primary',
                    },
                    true: {
                        text: 'Sim',
                        color: 'secondary',
                        handle: () => {
                            this.updateCurrentProduct({
                                ...product,
                                parent,
                            });
                            let selectedProduct = product.register.name;
                            notification('ANALYTICS_EVENT', {
                                event: 'product_selection',
                                payload: {
                                    selectedProduct,
                                },
                            });
                            this.$emit('onClose', { ...product });

                            
                            
                        },
                    },
                },
            });
        },
    },
```

In addition, when using GA debug extension that's what happens

[image]

I'm new to JavaScript and vue coding. That being said I tried to simply use a console.log in the exact same spot as the tag code and it is just being printed once and that's what's bugging me.

Is there something I could do to eliminate the double sending?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Don't use the ga debug extension. It's outdated. Use [Adswerve datalayer inspector](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/adswerve-datalayer-inspec/kmcbdogdandhihllalknlcjfpdjcleom). Pay attention to the last update date when installing extensions.
2. Double check the number of your events in the network tab to make sure they're really duplicating.
3. Show the screenshot of your dataLayer, check it for duplicates.
4. Don't implement analytics through gtag.js. Use GTM. Reasons? Maintainability, scalability, manageability, abstraction of completely unneeded complexity and awkward architecture of the gtag's api.

Comment: Any suggestion if console log shows the event creation code executed only once, but network tab shows the event is fired twice? The 2nd event comes after ~4-5s delay. Their payloads are exactly the same, except "_et" and "tfd" fields have different value, and "_ee" field is missing in 2nd event.

Comment: No, the extension should pick it up. If it doesn't, there's something wrong with the endpoint or the response code probably. But hey, try the Omnibug extension instead. The Adswerve's extension is core analytics only. Omnibug tries to capture all the marketing pixels plus the core analytics. Maybe that's a pixel you're looking at. Tho a pixel's payload would be significantly different.